# scala algebraic datatypes get member values

Tags: scala

I have defined below algebraic datatype in scala.

```
    sealed abstract class DeviceType(device : Option[Int])

    case object DeviceType {
    final case object Mobile extends DeviceType( device = Some(4) )
    final case object Tablet extends DeviceType ( device = Some(5) )
    final case object Desktop extends DeviceType( device = Some(2) )
    final case object TV extends DeviceType ( device = Some(3) )
    final case object Unknown extends DeviceType ( device = None )
    }
```

When I do `DeviceType.Mobile.device`, I get below error.

`error: value device is not a member of object DeviceType.Mobile`

How can I access the device member in the case objects in ADTs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `val` modifier to device attribute in order to have the accessor.

```
sealed abstract class DeviceType(val device : Option[Int])

   case object DeviceType {
       final case object Mobile extends DeviceType( device = Some(4) )
       final case object Tablet extends DeviceType ( device = Some(5) )
       final case object Desktop extends DeviceType( device = Some(2) )
       final case object TV extends DeviceType ( device = Some(3) )
       final case object Unknown extends DeviceType ( device = None )
    }
```